# Get relative xpath 1.0 to work for transalte

Tags: xpath, xpath-1.0

I have a parser that gets xml values using xpath and transforms it to a json file. I am trying to do some xpath and make it relative but can only get it working if I make it static(absolute).

```
translate(ns2:ModelYear, translate(ns2:ModelYear,'0123456789',''), '')"
```

and I set it as false for IsStaticPath, but that doesn't work, however it does work if I do:

```
translate(/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns4:ProcessMessageResponse/ns4:payload/ns4:content/ns2:ShowVehicleInvoice/ns2:ShowVehicleInvoiceDataArea/ns2:VehicleInvoice/ns2:Invoice/ns2:VehicleInvoiceVehicleLineItem/ns2:Vehicle/ns2:ModelYear, translate(/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns4:ProcessMessageResponse/ns4:payload/ns4:content/ns2:ShowVehicleInvoice/ns2:ShowVehicleInvoiceDataArea/ns2:VehicleInvoice/ns2:Invoice/ns2:VehicleInvoiceVehicleLineItem/ns2:Vehicle/ns2:ModelYear,'0123456789',''), '')"
```

and I set IsStaticPath to true, but I dont want to do that. Any ideas? Not sure if my xpath is wrong or my parser needs some fixing.

Comment: ns2:ModelYear.  Is the dot suppose to be there? typo?

Comment: Typo on my part, still doesnt work.

Comment: Then the only thing remaining is "your current node" (denoted by .) is not what you expect it to be (and should be) when/where you execute the relative version of the query.